# Riemann integral of function series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, riemann-integration

Let $f_n: [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ for } x = \frac{1}{i} \text{ with } i \in \{1, ..., n\}, \\
0 & \text{ otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

The task is:
a) Is $f_n$ Riemann integrable? If yes, calculate $\int \limits_{0}^{1}f_n(x)dx$

b) Consider $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by virtue of the pointwise limit $f(x):= \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$. Is $f$ Riemann integrable? If yes, what is the value of the integral?

---

My thoughts to a) are that $f_n$ ist integrable, because the points of discontinuity are finite for any given $n$. The value of the integral is 0.

To b) The pointwise limit should be $$f(x):= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ for } x = \frac{1}{k}, \; k \in \mathbb{N} \\
0 & \text{ otherwise.} \end{cases}$$
Now I suppose that f is not Riemann integrable, because the points of discontinuity are infinite (casually spoken), but I cannot prove it.

Any ideas? And are my thoughts to a) correct so far?

X3nius

Comment: For b) look at Lebesgue’s Criterion for integrablility on http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~rchen/Advanced%20Calculus/Lebesgue%20Criterion%20for%20Riemann%20Integrability.pdf

Comment: This is just the introduction to integration and Lebesgue, so we didn't have it yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

A is correct.  The limit function is correct, but it is integrable. You can have infinite discontinuities , the key is that they are measure 0.  You said in comments you don't have Lebesgue measure yet, fortunately for countable infinite discontinuities the proof is easy. For countability, it's pretty easy to prove directly via the Darboux equivalent version of the Riemann integral,  that for any $\epsilon>0$ you can find a partition $P$ such that the upper sum minus the lower sum on that partition is less than $\epsilon$.  Note that the lower sum is always 0 and your upper sum will just be the sum of the lengths of the intervals covering $\frac 1 k$ in your partition.   So cover each $\frac 1 k$  with an interval of width $\frac \epsilon {2^k}$, which is a geometric series that sums to $\epsilon$

Comment: Okay I've got some questions. 1) First of all, why is the lower sum always 0? Because in the interval of the width $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$ covering $\frac{1}{k}$ the infimum is 1?  2) How can the searched interval look like? Something like $\left[\frac{1}{k} + \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}\right]$ or $\left[\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}, \; \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}  \right]$?  3) Why does $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$ sum up to $\epsilon$? Doesn't $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$ sum up to $\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = 2$ ?

Comment: @X3nius the lower sum is 0 because in each part of your partition the infimum is 0, there are 0 values in every partition part.  the upper sums will only be non-zero in the partition parts including a a number of the form $|frac 1 k$.  ,  the latter option is how you do the intervals of the right link for 2:.   And for 3,  it depends on whether you start $k$ at $0$ or $1$.  At $k=1$ it sums to 1 as the first term (numerator) is $\frac 1 2$

Comment: Ahh yeah you are right! Okay, how could the intervals be partitionated, e.g. $\left[\frac{1}{k} - \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}\right]$? This idea just came up. But how can I then make sure that $\frac{1}{k+1}$ is part of 
$\left[\frac{\epsilon}{2^k} - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{k+1}}\right]$? I think this is not quite constructive..

Comment: I thought so much about it, but don't get a result. Could you maybe help me?

Comment: @X3nius Take as center points of each interval $\frac 1 k$.  Go  to the left and right of each of these points the minimum of $\frac \epsilon {2^{k+1}}$ or the distance to the next point with non-zero value,  IE up to $\frac $1 {k-1}$.   THe parts in covering the non-1 over a number parts, it doesn't matter how you partition that as you get 0

Comment: Three questions are left
1) Okay but if $k = 1$, I can't go to the right because $f(x)$ is defined over [0,1]. What can I do in this case? $\;\; \\\\$
2) Did I get it right that the distance of every interval is either identical $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$ or smaller than that (in case that the distance to the next point with non-zero value is less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{k+1}})$, but in the definition of the upper sum it will then be surely less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$? $\; \; \\\\$
3) What is the value of the integral in this case? 0?

Comment: For 1, sure,  you only need a 1 side interval,  so your last partition is $[1- \frac \epsilon 2,1]$.   For 2, yes,  we don't need the sum to be exactly $\epsilon$,  just less than that,  and then 3:  0, as we have the upper sum is smaller than any $\epsilon$ and the lower sum is $0$

Comment: Okay I got that, the last think I didn't get is the partitions. The last partition is $[1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2}, 1]$ with $\epsilon \le 2$. As next step, I take $\frac{1}{2}$ as the middle of the interval. But the problem now is, in case that $\epsilon = 2$, I already arrived at $\frac{1}{2}$ and so I can't go to the right anymore from $\frac{1}{2}$. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: And this holds generally for any $k$, so if I go to the left from $\frac{1}{k}$ with minimum $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{k+1}}$ and distance to $\frac{1}{k-1}$, and if the last value is the minimum, I'm already left of the next middle $\frac{1}{k+1}$. In the other case, so that minimum is $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{k+1}}$, I can end up left of $\frac{1}{k+1}$, exactly at $\frac{1}{k+1}$ or somewhere between $\frac{1}{k+1}$ and $\frac{1}{k}$. Could you maybe explain this to me, how I should choose declare the partition?

Comment: Start with 1, go backwards towards 0 with each each smaller step until your remaining width from $0$ to the last one you chose is smaller than the remaining part of $\epsilon$ you have to work with.

Comment: Could you maybe write that down with formulas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130340/discussion-between-x3nius-and-alan).